# how to override the default window.scrollTo function?

Tags: asp.net, validation, scrollto

My project is master/content. The client validation always scrolls the first control that is not valid to the top of the page (0, 0). I am trying to override the default window.scrollTo by putting following client-side script in the content page, but it doesn't seem working. Can anyone tell me what is wrong? I tried put this in the master page, not working either.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.scrollTo = function() { } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable FocusOnError Property